# Preventing Firefox add-on first page from showing up

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a Python program using Selenium Webdriver api that utilizes Firefox browser to browse, and I need the first page of the add on that shows it's version to be disabled and not gets shown when the browser gets to work. My add-on is NoScript.

Here is my code for Firefox profile :

```
def fpp():
    ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    ffprofile.add_extension(extension='NS.xpi')
    ffprofile.set_preference("extensions.noscript.currentVerison" , "2.6.9.35")
    ffprofile.update_preferences()
    return webdriver.Firefox(ffprofile)

def driver(url1):
   m = fpp()
   m.get(url1)
```

However, this line doesn't prevent the starting windows from showing up:

```
ffprofile.set_preference("extensions.noscript.currentVerison" , "2.6.9.35")
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noscript` preferences start with `noscript` (no need for `extensions.`). And you need to set the `version` instead of `currentVersion`. Works for me:

```
ffprofile.set_preference("noscript.version", "2.6.9.35")
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but the problem is still remained.

Comment: @The_Diver okay, correct me if I am wrong. Every time you run the script, you see the "noscript" welcome page opened in a new tab? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you so much for helping me.