# How to disable firstrun page in add-on - selenium - firefox - java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I am triggering firefox browser via selenium webdriver. I am adding extension/add-on "privacy badger" in selenium.Whenever I trigger browser I am getting first run html page from that addon `moz-extension://a1f88f6a-2513-490f-815f-f5d36dcae685/pages/welcome/welcome.html`

Is there any way to disable this in selenium ?

Adding extension via firefox profile

```
final String privacyBadgerAddonPath = "src/com/test/jk/addon/privacy-badger-latest.xpi";
firefoxProfile.addExtension(new File(privacyBadgerAddonPath));
```

firefox version : 52

Selenium version : 3.14.0

I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015040/preventing-firefox-add-on-first-page-from-showing-up?rq=1) but not sure how to use this for this addon.How do they come up with "noscript.version"

Thanks
Jk

Answer (score 0):

Selenium use by default a temporary browser profile. With existing browser profile you can use almost any customizations even add-ons. There is my setup with loading existing profile called "selenium_profile":

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
    FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
    options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

To create new Firefox profile hit Win+R and enter command "firefox.exe -p". The rest you'll manage.